# How to calculate the covariance matrix of 3d numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I have a matrix `A`, shaped `(N, D, 4)`. First I calculate `A` transposed, `A_t`. I want to calculate the product of `A_t` times `A`. I want the resulting matrix to be shaped `(D, D)`, and the product of the matrices be like if the last vector of 4 components was a number. (The dot product of two vectors is a number.)

```py
import numpy as np

N = 15
D = 98
A = np.random.random((N, D, 4))
A_t = np.zeros((D, N, 4))
for i in range(N):
    A_t[:, i] = A[i]

S = np.zeros((D, D))

for i in range(D):
    row = A_t[i]
    for j in range(D):
        col = A[:, j, :]
        val = 0
        for n in range(N):
            val += np.matmul(row[n], col[n])
        S[i][j] = val

print(A.shape)
print(A_t.shape)
print(S.shape)
```

Comment: The code does not show what you want to get from the matrix. You can transpose with just `A_t = A.T`. No need for the loop at all. Show a concrete sample with small arrays and `for` loops if you need to. Expected results are important here.

Comment: The code may not show it but is said it. I would like to get the product of A.t * A considering the vectors of 4 components as if they were just numbers so the resulting matrix i want would be DxD. The values of such matrix would be numbers resulting from the product of two vectors of 4 components.

Comment: Show what that means in code please. Your current code does not constitute an MCVE or really contribute anything useful to the discussion. Write a `for` loop if you have to. The product of two vectors can be defined in a number of ways. While I assume you mean dot product, it's unclear how you intend to combine the elements to get to that point.

Comment: Ok, let me try to be more clear, im sorry if I havent explained myself properly. First I cannot do A.T to find the transpose of A because when I do that the dimensions are not how I want this 3D matrix to be transposed. I have calculated the matrix I want using loops but I was wondering if theres a faster better way to do it. When the dimensions get bigger this method is too slow.

Comment: Thank you for posting the loop. Now it is 100% unambiguously clear what you are trying to do. I will post a solution soon

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through the operations you are attempting and see what we can do to simplify them. For starters, you can write

```
A_t = np.swapaxes(A, 0, 1)
```

This is equivalent to

```
A_t = np.transpose(A, [0, 1, 2])
```

or

```
A_t = A.transpose([0, 1, 2])
```

As it happens, neither is necessary for your current application. To see why, let's work with a simplified example:

```
np.random.seed(42)
N = 4
D = 3
K = 2
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (N, D, K))
```

In your outer loop, you have `row = A_t[i]`. But by definition of your transpose, this is identical to `row = A[:, i, :]`, making your life much easier, and the transpose superfluous.

The inner loop sums some dot products:

```
val = 0
for n in range(N):
    val += np.matmul(row[n], col[n])
```

If you remember the definition of a dot product, you will see that you are doing the equivalent of

```
np.sum(np.sum(row * col, axis=1), axis=0)
```

The inner sum is the sum-product in your loop, while the outer sum is the computation of `val`. Summing across both dimensions separately is just the same as summing the entire buffer at once, so we can immediately replace the inner loop with just

```
for i in range(D):
    for j in range(D):
        S[i][j] = np.sum(A[:, i, :] * A[:, j, :])
```

You can simplify this with either `np.dot`, `np.tensordot`, `np.einsum`, or just plain broadcasting. The first two are needlessly complicated because you are really sum-multiplying over two dimensions simultaneously. `np.einsum` offers the most direct solution overall, but it is a less straightforward translation of your code.

**Solution 1: Broadcasting**

Let's start with a straightforward broadcasting version of the double loop, before moving on to the more idiomatic solution:

```
S = (A[:, None, ...] * A[:, :, None, ...]).sum(axis=(0, -1))
```

or

```
S = np.sum(A[:, None, ...] * A[:, :, None, ...], axis=(0, -1))
```

This creates views of `A` shaped `(N, 1, D, K)` and `(N, D, 1, K)` respectively. The multiplication broadcasts the replicated `D` axes in each case to exactly what the `for` loops do, so the final sum over the `N` and `K` axes does exactly what the line `S[i][j] = np.sum(A[:, i, :] * A[:, j, :])` did before.

**Solution 2: np.einsum**

This solution lets you apply sum-product directly to whatever axes you want:

```
S = np.einsum('ijk,ihk->jh', A, A)
```

Notice that you must use a different letter for the second axis of the second matrix (`j` and `h`), to indicate that you will *not* be summing over that axis. `S` is symmetrical, but if it were not, you could transpose it by transposing to `->hj` in the result.

Comment: Thanks alot, i dont know if should ask a different question alltogether but knowing that matrix S is symetrical, real and semidefenite positive what is the best way to obtain its eigenvalues and eigenvectors sorted from big to small by the value of the eigenvalues??

Comment: @DanielCasasampera. That is trivially googleable. I would not recommend posting a question like that without doing some basic reearch first.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt home to test it, it does what I wanted, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: For some reason in my matrix it gives me negative values, is there a reason why?

Comment: When you dot two different vectors together, you can get a negative value. You shouldn't ever see one on the main diagonal though.